# Hybrid App - Native WebView wrapper vs Ionic approach

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor

we are planing to take the Hybrid approach when developing our new mobile app. 
Our main goals during development are:

- minimizing the App Stores submissions and approvals when doing the web UI changes
- implement fingerprint authentication, barcode scanner and push notifications on mobile
- if possible minimizing other teams involvement (we need something specific for iOS, so we don't have to wait for their planning)

Now with the help of our mobile team we are still deciding between two approaches and this is what we got so far:

1. Our mobile team creates a simple native wrapper app, where they implement the native functionality and display the deployed web app through WebView

   ＋ skipping App store submissions easily, we redeploy the web app and the main UI is updated

   ＋ native functionality is more reliable

   − three different projects/teams (Web, Android, iOS) and writing required native functionality separately

   − (from Apple guidelines) “Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website.” **With this approach, can we possibly run into trouble here? Since the main UI is not bundled with the native wrappers but pulled from our external website.**
2. We use Ionic/Capacitor

   ＋ one project/team with native functionality in one place

   ＋ UI bundled with native apps

   − skipping App store submissions only with paid Ionic Live app updates. **Is there other simple way to implement such live updates if your UI is bundled with the native apps?**

**Are my assumptions correct and are there any key points that we are missing or worth noting?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to build this yourself, like you describe in option 1. It will make a huge mess, waste a ton of time, and mean you have limited / untested code that you have to shoehorn your inner app into.

The Ionic Framework is already that wrapper that you are imagining, and it has great plugin support and documentation and cross platform tested code.

You should look into [Ionic AppFlow](https://ionicframework.com/appflow) which lets you deploy updated versions to the app.

By default you would just create a normal app with Ionic and it produces a new binary build and you deploy it each time to the app store.

If you use a service like AppFlow then you can redeploy the html parts of the app:

> **Live hot code updates**
>
> Deliver live app updates, content changes, A/B tests, bug fixes, and more—before or after your app is in the store. No lines, no waiting, no slowdowns.

This doesn't solve all problems. If you want to add a new feature that wants to add a new plugin, for example, adding a camera plugin, then you will need to make a new binary and submit it to the app store like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Would wholeheartedly disagree with rtpHarry here as my company has many enterprise customers utilizing our application and operating in exactly this scenario.  Currently not using Capacitor but plan to make this move to upgrade to a more modern native wrapper.  We have built a shell applications using plain HTML/JS/CSS that is responsible for loading a ReactJS bundle for it's core functionality.  We have found this configuration invaluable as it allows our enterprise customers to manage their own Bundle pushes as part of their release manangement...rather than us having to get involved in the actual deployment.  They can simply change a property in there MDM (for whatever segmentation of their users that is needed)  and have the shell retrieve an updated version of the bundle.  Also, AppFlow costs are heavily influenced by the usage of their push model...whereas the above technique is more flexible and free.